# async/await continuing too soon

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

So I'm basically trying to delay the invocation of filter process by 1.5 seconds to allow user to type multiple keystrokes in case they want to. If a new keystroke is typed, previously waiting task is cancelled and a new one starts waiting:

```
System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource token = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();

private async void MyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  token.Cancel();

  await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1500, token.Token);
  this.filterText = (sender as TextBox).Text;
  (this.Resources["CVS"] as CollectionViewSource).View.Refresh();

  //Earlier I had tried this variant too:
  //System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(500, token.Token).ContinueWith(_ =>
  //{
  //  this.filterText = (sender as TextBox).Text;
  //  (this.Resources["CVS"] as CollectionViewSource).View.Refresh();
  //});
}
```

But the filter process (`View.Refresh()` line) hits immediately on first keystroke without waiting. My impression was that calling `Cancel` on the token would kill `Delay()` and thereby the continuation task too, before planting the next one, but apparently this scheme doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: You cancelled the token that is used to cancel delaying. So no delay occurred.

Comment: Yeah, but is a token single-use thing? If not, see that i'm starting the new task AFTER cancelling the previous one.

Comment: After canceling, you have a canceled Token. You need a new CancellationTokenSource.

Comment: Your ContinueWith doesn't use the token so it has no influence on it. Use a ContinueWith  overload that actually uses the token.

Comment: @JHBonarius: Thanks. So `CancellationTokenSource` is a single-use thing. I thought it just provided a signaling mechanism and we could call `Cancel` multiple times. Anyway. thanks for the input.

Comment: `token.Token` <- you confuse yourself. `token` is not a token, it's a `CancellationTokenSource`. use proper naming, so it's clear what it is and what it does. And note, does `CancellationTokenSource` have a `Reset()` or `UnCancel()` method? No. You need a new one. Edit: I just see [it has a `TryReset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.tryreset). Still, might not be the best use-case.

Comment: Yes, bad naming there, I agree and will fix that. It didn't have a role in the problem btw. The real problem was that I thought CTS was able to signal cancellation any number of times, which would simply send a message to listening tasks. Now I see that it doesn't work like that.

Comment: If you fix it to create a new token after canceling the previous one then you could just fix it by checking if the token is canceled before running the code after the delay.  Note you'd want to capture the current token in a local variable so that you're checking the right one.

Comment: @juharr: *capture the current token in a local variable*... that is so easy to miss. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've thought about this some more, and suggest a new answer: see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to handle this is not with `Task.Delay` and exceptions (as exceptions are for exceptional circumstances), but using a `Timer` with the `Timer.Elapsed` event.

E.g.

```cs
using Timer = System.Windows.Forms.Timer;

private readonly Timer timer = new Timer();
private static string newText = "";

public Form1()
{
    timer.Interval = 1500;
    timer.Tick += OnTimedEvent;
}

private void MyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop(); // sets the time back to 0
    newText = (sender as TextBox).Text; // sets new text
    timer.Start(); // restarts the timer
}

private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
    filterText = newText;
    (Resources["CVS"] as CollectionViewSource).View.Refresh();
}
```

(Not sure this is 100% correct, but you get the gist.)

---

Old snippet relating to the discussions in the comments.

As the post says: this is not needed, as `Task.Delay` will link a listener to the `CancellationToken`, thus `.Cancel()` will block until all listeners have heard it.

```cs
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

private CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
private Task delayTask;

private async void TenantsFilter_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  cts.Cancel();
  if (delayTask != null) {
    try{await delayTask;}
    catch(TaskCanceledException){}
  }
  cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

  try
  {
    delayTask = Task.Delay(1500, cts.Token);
    await delayTask;
    this.filterText = (sender as TextBox).Text;
    (this.Resources["CVS"] as CollectionViewSource).View.Refresh();
  }
  catch(TaskCanceledException)
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: OK. I spent some more time reading about [how CancellationTokenSource works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495411/a-call-to-cancellationtokensource-cancel-never-returns). If my understanding is correct, `cts.Cancel` call in our code is blocking and waits for all registered callbacks to complete. Therefore, there shouldn't ideally be a race condition here.

Comment: @dotNET wow, great find. I learned something important today. I'll remove this answer tomorrow

Comment: Why `delayTask.Wait();` instead of `await delayTask;`?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias this answer is no longer right, but the task is already `await`ed in the `try` block. so the state machine is instantiated there (which handles everything, like exception handling). I don't think you need a second state machine, you just need to Wait=block until the task is done.

Comment: So you think that each `await` inside an `async` method results in an additional state machine? That's not how it works. Each `async` method results in one state machine, regardless of how many `await`s are inside the `async` method. Refraining from using `await` for this reason, and risking to block the UI thread by calling `.Wait()` on a task that may have not completed yet, is not justified.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias ah thanks. Pitifully I don't have that much experience with async/await, as the technical lead at my company banned them (he doesn't know them, doesn't trust them and doesn't want to learn them... he's weird)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias but if you `await`, you will also get the `TaskCanceledException`, right? My intention of using `Wait` was also to ignore any of that.

Comment: Yes, awaiting the `delayTask` will throw in case the task was not completed when the `cts.Cancel();` was called. But the same will happen if you `Wait()` the task instead. To prevent it from throwing, the easiest way is to catch and swallow the error: `try { await delayTask; } catch { }`

Comment: @TheodorZoulias interesting. I had a wrong assumption. Still this is all just weird to me. Exceptions should be used for exceptions, while here it's an integral part of the normal flow. I'm an old-schooler, and in the past we would use interrupts for this: one for keystrokes and one for the timer. That seems much simpler and expressive than this.

Comment: Cancellation in .NET is propagated as an exception. Don't ask me why, that's how the Microsoft engineers did it when they invented the `CancellationToken`. Maybe there was no better alternative. If you want to prevent an exception, but you want to avoid catch and swallow for performance reasons, you can do `await Task.WhenAny(delayTask);` or more economically `await delayTask.ContinueWith(_ => { }, default, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, TaskScheduler.Default);`. See also [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/22144 "Support await'ing a Task without throwing").

Comment: I would prefer using the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead of the `System.Timers.Timer`. The later invokes its `Elapsed` event on `ThreadPool` threads, and calling `Stop()` from the UI thread doesn't guarantee that the event will not fire anyway shortly after.

Answer (score 1):

If this helps anyone, the following is correctly working for me. My mistake was that I incorrectly assumed that CancellationTokenSource is a signaling device and could be used multiple times. That is apparently not the case:

```
private System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();
private async void TenantsFilter_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  cts.Cancel();
  cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();

  try
  {
    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1500, cts.Token);
    this.filterText = (sender as TextBox).Text;
    (this.Resources["CVS"] as CollectionViewSource).View.Refresh();
  }
  catch(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException ee)
  {
  }
}
```

Posting it here for my own record and just to let others check I'm still not doing anything wrong.

Comment: Thinking about this, I'm not sure this is 100% thread safe. `cts` is being referenced by another task/thread when you replace it. If the other thread has not seen the cancellation yet (which can happen, as scheduling is not e certainty), there might be a data race. You need to be sure of the other task is done before replacing it.

Comment: @JHBonarius: Hmm... Moreover, this could be called in quick successions by the user typing fast. What do u suggest? A monitor or mutex maybe?

Comment: I'm just thinking aloud, because it's not a trivial thing. But maybe assign the `Task.Delay` object to a private field before you await it. You can then `.Wait()` on it.

Comment: @JHBonarius - I'm not sure what you think that extra assignment does. By the time `await` is applied, the call to `Task.Delay` was already invoked, assessing the value of `cts.Token` and storing that internally. `await` is just working with whatever awaitable the `Task.Delay` method *returned*.

Comment: *For the lazy future reader, I'm pasting the same comment here too*. OK. I spent some more time reading about [how CancellationTokenSource works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495411/a-call-to-cancellationtokensource-cancel-never-returns). If my understanding is correct, cts.Cancel call in our code is blocking and waits for all registered callbacks to complete. Therefore, there shouldn't ideally be a race condition here.